# datepicker bootstrap initialization again

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I try to setup 2 datepickers for a simple checkin/checkout system by using the datepicker boostrap :http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Here my code:

```
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    var checkin = $('#searchtype_checkin').datepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        },
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 2);
            checkout.setValue(newDate);
        }
        checkin.hide();

        $('#searchtype_checkout')[0].focus();
    }).data('datepicker');

    var checkout = $('#searchtype_checkout').datepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        },
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        checkout.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
```

I got most of this code from the documentation. I've just made a little change. Here the logic I want to apply:

After select one date on the checkin, I want to disable all dates before this date in the checkout datepicker in order to avoid a checkout BEFORE the checkin as well as focus on the checkout directly on the event 'changeDate' of the checkin.

Everything works well BUT if after I changed my checkin date for a date BEFORE the date selected the first time, the checkout function "onRender" is not called again and all dates previously disabled ont the checkout datepicker are still disabled.

How can I call the onRender event again on the checkout datepicker ? I would like to call this function after each "changeDate" of the checkin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use option onSelect of datepicker instead of whatever you are using now.

```
 var checkin = $('#searchtype_checkin').datepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        },
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        onSelect: function(selected) {
                var date=new Date(selected)
                day=date.getDate()+2;
                newDate=date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + day + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                $("#searchtype_checkout").datepicker("option","minDate", newDate);
        }
});
```

**EDIT** - You can add onSelect to your checkout date too so that when a user selects the check out date first then all the later dates are disabled in the checkin date.

```
var checkout = $('#searchtype_checkout').datepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
                     return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                  },
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        onSelect: function(selected,inst) {
       $("#searchtype_checkin").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
     }
});
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CkfDP/1492/)**

Comment: sorry maybe I didn't explain well what I try to do. The main issue is not to set the checkout date but the issue is to disable the checkout date before the checkin date dynamically.

Comment: So you want to enable checkout date only after checkin date in selected right?

Comment: **Everything works well BUT if after I changed my checkin date for a date BEFORE the date selected the first time, the checkout function "onRender" is not called again and all dates previously disabled on the checkout datepicker are still disabled.** This is what you have mentioned in your question and as per my answer it solves your problem. Please be specific or edit the question!

Comment: sorry for me it's clear on the question too. If for exemple I select 05/01/2015 on the checkin, checkout available dates starts from 06/01/2015, which is what I want BUT, if now I change my checkin date to 01/01/2015, the checkout available date still starts from the 06/01/2015 which is incorrect because at this point, I should be able to select 03/01/2015 for exemple. You see ?

Comment: that's why I've asked to dynamically use the onRender method on the checkout each time I change the checkin.

Comment: Ok.. can you provide a fiddle with simple html?? I'll try to edit that!!

Comment: I've tried to find this library to use it on Fiddle but I couldn't find that in any CDN. I't the first time to me to use Fiddle maybe I don't do the right thing ? Sorry for my ignorance. I think my solution will be to use a date-range from this library: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ instead of datepicker bootstrap from eyecon

Comment: I think there will not be much difference between both. What I referred was `jquery-ui-datepicker` and what you are referring is the edited version of same in terms of styles with some less options to play around compared to `jquery-ui-datepicker`. So it doesn't matter if you give it in `jquery-ui-datepicker`. I'll try creating the same with your code and will let you know.

Comment: I would suggest you to go with date-range of the link what you have mentioned. Let me know if you face any issue implementing the same!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)